# How to fix an if statement for a moving object?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

I have an object moving when I press some keys. It also moves diagonally when I press two keys. The issue is the following:

1. I press 'd', the object goes left.
2. I keep left pressed and I also press 'w'. The object moves diagonally.
3. I release 'w', while 'd' is still pressed. The object stops moving, although 'd' is still down.

How can I fix that?

```
let keysPressed = ["a", "w", "d", "s"];
const box1 = document.getElementById("box1");


document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
keysPressed[event.key] = true;
var box1x = box1.offsetLeft;
var box1y = box1.offsetTop;
if (keysPressed['d'] && keysPressed['s']) {
   box1.style.left = box1x + 20 + 'px';
   box1.style.top = box1y + 20 + 'px';
} else if (keysPressed['a'] && keysPressed['s']) {
   box1.style.left = box1x - 20 + 'px';
   box1.style.top = box1y + 20 + 'px';
} else if (keysPressed['w'] && keysPressed['a']) {
   box1.style.left = box1x - 20 + 'px';
   box1.style.top = box1y - 20 + 'px';
} else if (keysPressed['w'] && keysPressed['d']) {
   box1.style.left = box1x + 20 + 'px';
   box1.style.top = box1y - 20 + 'px';
} else if (keysPressed['w']) {
   box1.style.top = box1y - 20 + 'px';
} else if (keysPressed['s']) {
   box1.style.top = box1y + 20 + 'px';
} else if (keysPressed['a']) {
   box1.style.left = box1x - 20 + 'px';
} else if (keysPressed['d']) {
   box1.style.left = box1x + 20 + 'px';
}
});
```

Comment: You are not setting `keysPressed[event.key]` back to false on `keyup`, do you?

Comment: Also, use a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are never setting the `keysPressed` value to `false` the state remains the same, even if you release the key.

You could write it like this:

```
let keysPressed = ['a', 'w', 'd', 's'];
const box1 = document.getElementById('box1');

const tick = () => {
    let box1x = box1.offsetLeft;
    let box1y = box1.offsetTop;
    if (keysPressed['d'] && keysPressed['s']) {
        box1.style.left = box1x + 20 + 'px';
        box1.style.top = box1y + 20 + 'px';
    } else if (keysPressed['a'] && keysPressed['s']) {
        box1.style.left = box1x - 20 + 'px';
        box1.style.top = box1y + 20 + 'px';
    } else if (keysPressed['w'] && keysPressed['a']) {
        box1.style.left = box1x - 20 + 'px';
        box1.style.top = box1y - 20 + 'px';
    } else if (keysPressed['w'] && keysPressed['d']) {
        box1.style.left = box1x + 20 + 'px';
        box1.style.top = box1y - 20 + 'px';
    } else if (keysPressed['w']) {
        box1.style.top = box1y - 20 + 'px';
    } else if (keysPressed['s']) {
        box1.style.top = box1y + 20 + 'px';
    } else if (keysPressed['a']) {
        box1.style.left = box1x - 20 + 'px';
    } else if (keysPressed['d']) {
        box1.style.left = box1x + 20 + 'px';
    }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    keysPressed[event.key] = true;
    tick();
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    keysPressed[event.key] = false;
    tick();
});
```